# css3 - custom drop down list

Tags: asp.net, css

i have asp drop down list and i want to change the style of the right arrow

so , i put this line in my drop down class:

```
" background:  url(Arrow.PNG) no-repeat right center;"
```

Now i want to "drow" the arrow with css3 instead of using arrow.png picture

i have this class that paint arrow:

```
.PaintArrow {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    border-width: medium 2px 2px medium;
    border-style: none solid solid none;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color #D1202F #D1202F -moz-use-text-color;
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: border 0.2s ease-out 0s;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    right: 14px;
    top: 36px;
    }
```

How can i connect this class to the background of my drop down(on the right size)??

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about asp.net, but if normal CSS and HTML Elements work there, you could do something like the following.

Let's say your List-Element is called **dropdown-li**, which is a class in our case.

Then you could use the pseudo-element :before.

```
.dropdown-li:before {
    /* All the styles you defined above in your Question. */
}
```

Hopefully I could help out, greetings.

---

Here is a demonstration-fiddle with some edited styles: http://jsfiddle.net/f79osge3/

Comment: The problem with this is that the "before element" is not clickable and not open the drop down list

Comment: Do you have an a-element and want the :before Pseudoelement to be clickable aswell?